# Multi index to single index in python

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

output of df.pivot:

```
Tags    350384  350385  350386  350387  350388  350389  350390  350391
UserID
693          0       1       0       1       0       0       0       1
730          0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
906          0       0       0       2       0       0       0       2
1013         0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
1284         0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

I want this to be converted in the form:

```
UserID   350384  350385  350386  350387  350388  350389  350390  350391
693          0       1       0       1       0       0       0       1
730          0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
906          0       0       0       2       0       0       0       2
1013         0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
1284         0       0       0       0       0       0       0       0
```

Comment: there are no multi-index there, do `df.columns.name = None` if you do not want the frame to look like that

Comment: Thanks you for taking time. If I will rephrase my question, I want to add UserID as one of the column. If I will do df.columns.none, It will not help. Can you help me now?

Comment: ``df.reset_index()``